# Не срабатывает класс col-sm bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap

Имеется код https://jsfiddle.net/kddxn76r/
Почему не срабатывает класс `col-sm-6`, на каждой строке должно быть по 2 колонки.

```css
.bottom_line {
    padding: 20px 0;
    background-color: #F7F8FA;
}
.bottom_line .b_first span {
    font-family:"Intro", sans-serif;
    font-size: 42px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.bottom_line .b_first .first {
    color: #454545;
}
.bottom_line .b_first .second {
    color: #959595;
}
.bottom_line .b_first p {
    font-family:"Museo Sans Cyrl 500", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<section class="bottom_line">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <div class="col-md-3 сol-sm-6">
                    <div class="b_first"> <span class="first">Reve</span>  <span class="second">nant</span>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec tetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam non ummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut lao reet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 сol-sm-6">
                    <div class="b_first"> <span class="first">Reve</span>  <span class="second">nant</span>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec tetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam non ummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut lao reet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 сol-sm-6">
                    <div class="b_first"> <span class="first">Reve</span>  <span class="second">nant</span>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec tetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam non ummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut lao reet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 сol-sm-6">
                    <div class="b_first"> <span class="first">Reve</span>  <span class="second">nant</span>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec tetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam non ummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut lao reet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Разместите ваш код прямо в вопросе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перепишите `col-sm-6` https://jsfiddle.net/kddxn76r/4/ там у вас ошибка какая-то буква скорее всего русская.

```css
.bottom_line {
    padding: 20px 0;
    background-color: #F7F8FA;
}
.bottom_line .b_first span {
    font-family:"Intro", sans-serif;
    font-size: 42px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.bottom_line .b_first .first {
    color: #454545;
}
.bottom_line .b_first .second {
    color: #959595;
}
.bottom_line .b_first p {
    font-family:"Museo Sans Cyrl 500", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<section class="bottom_line">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="b_first"> <span class="first">Reve</span>  <span class="second">nant</span>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec tetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam non ummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut lao reet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="b_first"> <span class="first">Reve</span>  <span class="second">nant</span>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec tetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam non ummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut lao reet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="b_first"> <span class="first">Reve</span>  <span class="second">nant</span>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec tetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam non ummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut lao reet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="b_first"> <span class="first">Reve</span>  <span class="second">nant</span>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec tetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam non ummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut lao reet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```